# E. Assiut Chess

Tags: python

I have been trying this problem on codeforces.com https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1557/E
for the last couple of hours but I am unsure of what is going wrong with my code.
It works on almost everything except on test 12 test case 8. If any tries this out here is my code. Also if you could find the problem with this please let me know.

```
numCases = int(input(""))
for i in range(numCases):
    direction = 'right'
    goDown = False
    Qcoord = [1, 1]
    print(Qcoord[0], Qcoord[1], flush=True)
    dir = input('')

    while (dir != 'Done'):
        if goDown == True:
            if direction == 'right':
                Qcoord[1] += 1
            else:
                Qcoord[1] -= 1
            goDown = False
        else:
            if Qcoord[1]==8 and Qcoord[0]==7:
                direction='left'
                Qcoord[1]-=1
            elif Qcoord[1]==1 and Qcoord[0]==7:
                direction='right'
                Qcoord[1] += 1
            elif Qcoord[1] < 8 and direction == 'right':
                Qcoord[1] += 1
            elif Qcoord[1] == 8 and direction == 'right':
                direction = 'left'
                Qcoord[0] += 1
                goDown = True
            elif Qcoord[1] > 1 and direction == 'left':
                Qcoord[1] -= 1
            elif direction == 'left' and Qcoord[1] == 1:
                direction = 'right'
                Qcoord[0] += 1
                goDown = True

        print(Qcoord[0], Qcoord[1], flush=True)
        dir = input('')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about not looking at the feedback, then deterministically move to checkmate anyway?

```py
numCases = int(input(''))
dir = ''
while dir != 'Done':
  for i in range(numCases):
    for x in range(1,8):
      print(x, 1, flush=True)
      dir = input('')
    for y in range(2,8):
      print(7, y, flush=True)
      dir = input('')
```

We can just always place the queen at 1,1 from the beginning and move towards 7,7 in a chocking style. I'm still wrapping my mind around the abomination of not allowing the king to capture the queen at all as per the given example in the webpage, so I devised this solution accordingly!!